# Resizable photos on drag when photo is rotatated expand on diagonal not x axis

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation, axis

I have resizable photos that I resize on drag. When there is no rotation I expand on the x axis by getting the X current mouse and on drag the next X mouse position.

My photos can also be rotated so when the photo has a rotation I don't want to expand the photo by the px that the mouse has moved on the x axis, but from the diagonal towards which the photo is rotated. Is there a way to do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/p1j9nys5/4/

What I want is when I expand the second div (the rotated one) the expanding to be calculated from the diagonal at the direction of the arrow not the X axis.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class='img'>
    <div class="expand-btn">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class='img'>
    <div class="expand-btn">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

const divs = [...document.getElementsByClassName('img')];
divs.forEach(div => {
    div.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
});

let posX;
let posY;
let node;
function startDrag(e){
    node = e.currentTarget;
    posX = e.clientX;
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', resize);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
}
function resize(e){
    const nextPosX = e.pageX;
    node.style.width = node.offsetWidth + (nextPosX - posX) + 'px';
    posX = nextPosX;
}
function stopDrag(e){
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', resize);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
}

.container{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container:nth-child(2){
  top: 160px;
  left: 50px;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.img{
  width: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
.img div{
  top: 42.5%;
  right: 10%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
div span{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
div span:nth-child(1){
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
div span:nth-child(2){
  right: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background: red;
}
```